# Error: attempt to apply non-function for sparklyr ml_lda ml_describe_topics

Tags: r, machine-learning, topic-modeling, sparklyr

I am trying to run a LDA model with sparklyr. The documentation suggests that I ca use the function ml_describe_topics on my model to extract the most relevant words for each topic, but when I run this I get an error.

An example of my code is below:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

    lda_model <- input_text %>%
      ft_tokenizer(input_col = "text_data", output_col = "word_tokens") %>%
      mutate(all_words = explode(word_tokens)) %>%
      ml_lda(~all_words, k = 3, max_iter = 100)

    lda_model %>% ml_describe_topics
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in model$describe_topics(max_terms_per_topic) :  Error in model$describe_topics(max_terms_per_topic) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
Error in model$describe_topics(max_terms_per_topic) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
In addition: Warning message:
In do.call(.f, args, envir = .env) :
  'what' must be a function or character string
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is going wrong here? I'm very confused why the function isn't working for me, especially when this follows the examples in the documentation that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

i ran into this error as well.
For me, the issue was that `ml_lda()` returned a `pipeline_model` rather than the model itself. The model is part of this structure. This is not very clear from the documentation.

Calling the function with `ldamodel$model` has the desired result:

`ml_describe_topics(ldamodel$model)` -->

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
   topic termIndices termWeights
   <int> <list>      <list>     
 1     0 <int [10]>  <dbl [10]> 
 2     1 <int [10]>  <dbl [10]> 
 3     2 <int [10]>  <dbl [10]> 
(...)
```